# Spring Data JPA/Hibernate - using EntityManager for queries

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have these entities, from which I want get List of Tuples containing information from both of them: [image: Users and People Entities]

which should look like this:

```
+--------+-----+---------+
|name    |login|user_type|
+--------+-----+---------+
|        |admin|admin    |
|John Doe|john |user     |
|Jane Doe|janed|user     |
|........|.....|.........|
```

The thing is, my JPA skill got quite rusty and I forgot how to use Entity Managers. I know how to make basic JPQL queries or build-in stuff, but sadly it's not enough for me (since I need to use that list for filling up table in my UI). So, how did I should use Entity Managers? (if I should use that at all ;) )

Edit: now I think that using DTO projection is better;  here's my mapping class

```
public class PersonUserMap {
    private Integer personID;
    private String name;
    private String login;
    private UserType userType;
    public Integer getPersonID() {
        return personID;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }
    public UserType getUserType() { //custom Enum
        return userType;
    }
}
```

my annotation in People class:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "PersonUserMapping",
    classes = @ConstructorResult(
        columns = { @ColumnResult(name = "personID", type=Integer.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "name"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "login"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "userType",type = UserType.class)},
        targetClass = PersonUserMap.class))
```

and when using native query like this:

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("Select p.personid, p.first_name || ' ' || p.last_name as name, u.login, u.user_type from people p join users u on p.user_idusers = u.idusers","PersonUserMapping");
```

it throws exception `Could not resolve column name in result set [userType]`

Comment: Maybe more details on what you need specifically. If you can execute queries, what are you looking to do that is outside of that skill - "Select user.login, user.email, person from User user where .." isn't very different a query from "Select user from User user where..", or "select person from People person", the later of which will give you person instances that should include their referenced user

Comment: @Chris I want to get in my Tuple these properties: - firstName and lastName from People entity - login and userType from Users entity; (in mysql terms: `SELECT first_name, last_name, users.login, users.user_type FROM database.people FULL JOIN database.users ON user_idusers = users.idusers;
`) this Tuple will be used to filling Vaadin Grid with all of users

Comment: Not a fan of tuple queries as they must bypass entity caching mechanisms, but what you have is similar to the first query I suggested with a join. "Select p.firstName, p.lastName, u.login, u.userType from People p join p.user u"

Comment: @Chris could you check my post now?

Comment: Why are you using a native query (SQL) instead of a JPQL query? JPQL gives you validation of your queries, that the columns exist as your model changes, and should be easier for devs using your entities to read and understand. Your PersonUserMapping's userType definition is incorrect, as the error states you are forcing it to look for "userType" which doesn't exist in the returned result set. You need it to look for 'user_type', or change your query to return 'userType' instead.

Comment: @Chris now when I used `TypedQuery<Object[]> q = entityManager.createQuery("Select p.personid, concat(p.firstName,  p.lastName) as name, u.login, u.userType from People p join Users u",Object[].class);` (which I later convert to `PersonUserMap`), it throws exception `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`, which makes me completely dumbfounded :/

Comment: Show the SQL it generates (turn SQL logging on) and the full error. And the database and driver versions

Comment: `Hibernate: 
    select
        people0_.personid as col_0_0_,
        concat(people0_.first_name,
        ' ',
        people0_.last_name) as col_1_0_,
        users1_.login as col_2_0_,
        users1_.user_type as col_3_0_ 
    from
        people people0_ 
    inner join
        users users1_ 
            on` (well, it makes sense why it throws error since there's no join condition; also it makes inner join, when I need full join)

full error: https://pastebin.com/Si480yVy

DB: mysql  Ver 8.0.27
connector: mysql connector/j 8.0.27

Comment: @Chris also I just clarified how I want resulting table to look

Comment: I didn't notice you had "from People p join Users u" as your query - Why didn't you use "from People p join p.user u" as suggested? JPA doesn't have full joins - it isn't universally supported on databases, so right and left joins are all that are offered. You should be easily able to make your native query work - I have you the solution in my second post with the 'userType' being incorrect as 'user_type' is what would be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @Chris help I finally got somewhere; my set mapping is looking like this:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "PersonUserMapping",
    classes = @ConstructorResult(
        columns = { @ColumnResult(name = "personid", type=Integer.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "name"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "login"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "user_type",type = UserType.class)},
        targetClass = PersonUserMap.class))
```

and my query looks like this

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select personid, concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as 'name', users.login, users.user_type from aspirejestracja.people"
                + " full join aspirejestracja.users on user_idusers = users.idusers ", "PersonUserMapping");
```

now I can display all users which I need :)